# Select2 remote data with pre selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to load select2 remote data and also with some selected value.

My code is like this

```
$("#category_input").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#changeCategoryModal"),
    placeholder: "Change Category",
    closeOnSelect: false,
    maximumSelectionLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        processResults: function(response) {
            return {
                results: response,
            };
        }
    }
});
```

If I want to make id 1,2,3 (Example) selected, What can I do here ?

(I am using this script in Laravel blade template)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your query correct, you can try this below approach.

**Approach:**

- We track the AJAX request in **fetch_data** function
- Process our data in the function and render that data from blade
- And finally return the response to AJAX request

**controller.php**

```
public function fetch_data()
{
    if(request()->ajax()) {

        //process your data and logics

        //here is some sample data to understand the flow
        $selected_options = array(1, 3);

        $data = array(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'produc1'], ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'produc2'], ['id' => 3, 'name' => 'produc3']);
        
       return view('select2', compact('selected_options', 'data'))->render();
    }
}
```

**select2.blade.php**

```
@foreach($data as $key => $val)

    <option value="{{$val['id']}}" @if(in_array($val['id'], $selected_options)) selected @endif> $val['name'] </option>

@endforeach
```